# PHP/jQuery AJAX JSON error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

When I was trying to recieve a code from PHP page using jQuery Ajax, I found a strange error:
"Undefined variable: errors"

```
<?php
$errors = array("already_signed" => "You are already signed in", "field_empty" => "All fields must be filled", "long_username" => "Username length must be less then 40 symbols", "incorrect_email" => "Your mail is incorrent", "user_exists" => "User with such username already exists", "account_not_found" => "Account not found", "passwords_arent_same" => "Passwords must be the same");
Function check_post() {
    $answer = array("ok" => "false", "answer" => $errors["field_empty"]);
    echo json_encode($answer);
}

check_post();
?>
```

If I'll echo without function - everything will be ok.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Also, quick question, in PHP shouldn't `Function` be `function`? http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: "Undefined variable: errors"? PHP

Comment: @oscar: php function names and keywords are case insensitive. variables, on the other hand, are case sensitive.

Comment: @marc awh, didn't know. Strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access a global variable from within the function. In order to acomplish that, you need to use "global" keyword:

```
<?php
$errors = array("already_signed" => "You are already signed in", "field_empty" => "All fields must be filled", "long_username" => "Username length must be less then 40 symbols", "incorrect_email" => "Your mail is incorrent", "user_exists" => "User with such username already exists", "account_not_found" => "Account not found", "passwords_arent_same" => "Passwords must be the same");
function check_post() {
    global $errors;
    $answer = array("ok" => "false", "answer" => $errors["field_empty"]);
    echo json_encode($answer);
}
check_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be missing at least one `}` in there. As is, your function definition has no close, so it reads as an infinitely recursive call.

As well, you've got `$errors` being defined OUTSIDE of your function. PHP does not allow "lower" code scopes to see variables defined in higher scopes. You need to declare $errors as a global within the function:

```
<?php

$errors = array(....);
function check_post() {
   global $errors;
   $answer = ...
   ...
}

check_post();
```